# How to specify "no-port"

Tags: linux, port

I am trying to document a "connection string" which includes the host:port to grab data from a file or database. For example, to connect to ssh we have:

```
myhost.com:22/
```

And to connect to MySQL we have something like:

```
mydatabase.org:3306/
```

What is the convention used to show a port that is irrelevant, for example, for a local file, something like:

```
localhost:*/
```

Comment: What do you mean "the port is not relevant"? Does it mean that you can reach it via any port?

Comment: @noam -- it would be the equivalent of double clicking it on a local machine, or in opening the file from an HTML 'browse' button in the local browser.

Answer (score 0):

To simply not include it:

```
localhost/
```